# Remove parentheses, dashes, and spaces from phone number

Tags: java, regex

I have a phone number like (123) 456-7890. I am using the `replaceAll` method to remove `()` and `-` and spaces from the string. I tried following

```
String phNo= "(123) 456-7890".replaceAll("[()-\\s]").trim();
```

but it's not working. Any solution?

Comment: show us your code and output.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? (Anyway, the issue is that `-` has meaning inside a character class, use `"[-()\\s]"`)

Answer (score 21):

This should work:

```
String phNo = "(123) 456-7890".replaceAll("[()\\s-]+", "");
```

In your regex:

- `\s` should be `\\s`
- Hyphen should be first or last in character class to avoid escaping or use it as `\\-`
- Use quantifier `+` as in `[()\\s-]+` to increase efficiency by minimizing # of replacements

Answer (score 6):

IN 2022 use this! all other answers too old!!!!!!!!!!!

```
result = "(123) 456-7890".replace(/[^+\d]+/g, "");
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer for JavaScript, but this question is tagged as Java. I don't think `replace` works the same way in both.

Comment: Worked for my JavaScript/TypeScript needs!

Answer (score 5):

If you want the phone number then use:

```
String phNo = "(123) 456-7890".replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

This regex will mark all characters that are not digits, and replace them with an empty string.

---

The regex: `\D+`

- Match a single character that is not a digit.  `\D`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible. `+`

Comment: This won’t work for phone numbers that contain a plus sign, i.e. that use `+` as the international call prefix.

Answer (score 4):

```
  String newStr = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        System.out.println(newStr);
```

Removes All Non-Digit Characters.

[Java Regex - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `-` character with brackets `[]` indicates a character range, e.g. `[a-z]`.  However, the character range doesn't work here where you want a literal `-` to be used.  Escape it.

```
String phNo = "(123) 456-7890".replaceAll("[()\\-\\s]", "").trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two main reasons this does not work as expected.

1. Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special meaning**. You can place a hyphen as the first or last character of the class. In some regular expression implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it in order to add it to your class.

   ```
   String phNo = "(123) 456-7890".replaceAll("[()\\-\\s]").trim();
                                                 ^^
   ```
2. You are not supplying a replacement value which neither answer has pointed out to you.

   ```
   String phNo = "(123) 456-7890".replaceAll("[()\\-\\s]", "").trim();
                                                           ^^
   ```

   And finally, you can remove `.trim()` here as well.

   ```
   String phNo = "(123) 456-7890".replaceAll("[()\\-\\s]", "");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin than

**`mobileNo.replace(Regex("[()\\-\\s]"), "")`**