# How to remove parenthesis around the phone number

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-phone-call

I'm loading the data into a RecyclerView. I want that after click on "mobile number string" it should be open in phone app without parenthesis means I want to open it in phone like a simple "Indian phone number".
In my code it is open like this (879) 321-2686.

```
    holder.tv_mobileno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+product.getMobileno()));
            ctx.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

This is the image of the RecyclerView:

[image]

This is the output of phone app

[image]

Comment: why do you wanna remove the paranthesis ?

Comment: why not just find replace?

Comment: but i have to display the phone number in indian number format style

Comment: This is how the native phone app works. There is little you can do about it.

Comment: my guess is, its about the phone call app , it is formatting the number all by itself so you cannot do anything about it

Comment: Try `i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"91" +product.getMobileno()));`

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25089392/5110595)

Comment: i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"+91" +product.getMobileno())); //this solves my problem

Comment: @RohitSuthar If you are rolling app to market then user might store number with different country code. However your code is working fine and displaying **87932 12686** (Indian format) on Phone app version 3.0.0.

Comment: ya but my app is only for my city in india

Comment: No i  testing app on android emulator

Answer (score 1):

```
holder.tv_mobileno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+91" + product.getMobileno())); // --> add +91
        ctx.startActivity(i);
      }
});
```

Comment: it should be +91

Answer (score 0):

Take a String "mobNo" which holds the mobile number and then delete the first and fourth character, then call your method.

```
 i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+mobNo);
```

Comment: The paranthesis are added by Phone app, they aren't explicitly passed by program.